# baCentral limit theorem for uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

We are given $X_1, X_2, ...$ independent random variables with uniform distribution on $[80,100]$.

What is the probability that for $n=100$ at least half of the variables has value $X_i \ge 95$?

I think this is what we are looking for here $P(S_{50} \ge 50 \cdot 95)$. This would give us  $P(Z_{50} \ge 0,8659)$ so something is wrong, because that is very close to $1$.

Could you tell me where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: You are asked for the number of $i$s such that $X_i\geqslant95$, not about the value of the sum of the $X_i$s. No CLT on the sequence $(X_i)$ here.

Comment: The number of integers $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$ such that $X_i\geqslant95$ is a random integer $N$ such that $0\leqslant N\leqslant n$. Your task is to find the distribution of $N$.

Comment: Please read carefully the comments posted to help you.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So for example $P(N=0) = P(X_1 < 95)...P(X_n<95) = (3/4)^n$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas That's right. $ P(N \ge 50) =$ $ 100\choose 50 $ $ (1/4)^{50} (3/4)^{50}$

Comment: Please see my previous comment. The probability that $N\ge 50$ is not what you wrote down. The system is objecting to the long string of comments, so I will delete most of mine. I suggest you do the same.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see, we choose at least $50$, not exactly $50$ variables. So $100 \choose 50$ isn't enough.

Comment: You should be able to write down a sum for $\Pr(N\ge 50)$. A long sum! That can be evaluated by software. However, you may be expected to use a standard approximation.  When you solve the problem, you should consider writing out an answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas $ \sum_{0\leq{k}\leq{n}}\binom nk = 2^n, \ n=100$ so we could divide it by two and add $ 1/2$ $ 100 \choose 50 $, to get the sum of $100 \choose k$ for all $k \ge 50$

Comment: @AndréNicolas Would that give the solution?

Comment: No, the random variable $N$ has binomial distribution, $n=100$, $p=1/4$. The exact formula for the probability is $\sum_{k=50}^{100}\binom{100}{k}(1/4)^k(3/4)^{100-k}$. To evaluate approximately you may wish to use the normal approximation to the binomial.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you. Could you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarising, if we let $N=$the number of $i \in {1,...,100}$ for which $X_i \ge 95$, we have:

$$P(N=k) = \binom{100}{k} P(X_1 \ge 95)^k P(X_1 < 95)^{100-k} = \binom{100}{k}(1/4)^k(3/4)^{100-k}$$ so $$P(N\ge 50) = \sum_{k=50}^{100}\binom{100}{k}(1/4)^k(3/4)^{100-k}$$

If we want to evaluate the probability with $0,001$ accuracy, we use the central limit theorem for $N \in \mathcal{B}(100, \frac{1}{4})$ and standardize the variable $N$.

Then $N$ has approximately distribution $N(25, 4,33)$ and therefore $P(N \ge 50) \approx 1- \phi(\frac{50-25}{4,33}) \approx 1- \phi(5,77) \approx 0$

Comment: The variance is $100(1/4)(3/4)=18.75$, so the standard deviation is about $4.33$. We have $(50-25)/4.33\approx   5.77$, very large, so the probability is $0$ for all practical purposes. You did things fine, except for forgetting to take the square root. Actually, with experience one would without computation see that $50$ or more successes when the probability of success is only $1/4$ is enormously unlikely.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Great, thank you. I'll correct that :)